# PHP GET dynamic key

Tags: php, get

It is possible to get the first `$_GET` key without specify it's name?

I want to do something like that, calling this php file like: `index.php?foo=something` or `index.php?bar=something`

```
// $_GET[dynamic] stays for something to get the key.. that can be foo or bar in this example

switch($_GET[dynamic]){
    case 'foo':
        switch(@$_GET['foo']){
            //cases depending on $_GET['foo'] value
        }
    break;
    case 'bar':
        switch(@$_GET['bar']){
            //cases depending on $_GET['bar'] value
        }
    break;
}
```

Comment: get query string -> explode('&') -> explode('=') get first item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a = key($_GET);
```

will return the  first value in the query string.

Comment: This would get the first value based on alphabetizing?

Comment: @Class, this will get the first value in the query string.

Comment: I thought that get's get sorted at least I think I'm not 100% sure since I'm going based on what I remember.

Comment: +1 I checked and it doesn't sort them and your code works great (TIL GET's don't get sorted, Thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

Don't make it to complicated and remind, that you should avoid deep nesting.

```
if (isset($_GET['foo']) {
  $value = $_GET['foo'];
} else if (isset($_GET['bar'])) {
  $value = $_GET['bar'];
}
switch ($value) {
  // and so on
}
```

Oh, and try to avoid full-dynamic keys as this makes it hard to keep them valid and secure :)

Comment: I was using that before, but since i plan to have a lot of cases, i was wondering if there was a faster method.

Comment: @WiS3 You should think about why you need "a lot of cases".

Comment: Because i'm making a single page where i can call all actions that a a user can do, and also some script inclusion.

Comment: And that relies on the _key_? Whats about the obvious solution: A key with the name `action` and thats it?

Comment: I have posted only a example, but in my script, i have login, register, logout, function. Then i have image functions, like upload, view, and so on... Instead to have `?action=ALLGOESHERE`, i prefer to have it divided like: `?action=login/register`, `?image=upload/view`

Comment: @WiS3 You know, that you can have as many key-value-pairs as you like? `?action=upload&type=image`. That is definitely the cleaner solution.